# Can I use same software after switching Window Manager or Desktop Environment in Linux

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments, window-manager, kwin

I am using Kubuntu and I have Kwin as the Window Manager and KDE as the Desktop Environment.

I use VSCode and other software.

I am switching to another Desktop Environment and Window Manager alongside Kwin and KDE.

This means I will have both KDE and other Desktop Environments installed on my computer and I will switch between these from login screen. The same is true for the window manager.

If I switch to Cinnamon Desktop Environment or GNOME Desktop Environment or any other Desktop Environment, or if I switch to  `i3`, `bspwm`, `dwm` Tiling Window Manager or `Fluxbox`, `Openbox` Stacking/Floating Window Manager, or if I switch both Desktop Environment and Window Manager, can I use the same VSCode and other software on these different Desktop Environments and Window Managers, or do I need to install same software for each of these Desktop Environments and Window Managers?

Comment: All the same software should work on any DE or WM.

Comment: @David You can post that as an answer

Comment: Some desktops are WM *agnostic*, however some are not.  I'm using Lubuntu thus LXQt desktop which is a WM *agnostic*; Lubuntu uses `openbox` as its WM; Debian use `xfwm4`...  Yes almost all DEs *should* work with any WM, however you'll discover you may not get all functionality working as some are coded and expect certain WMs to be used.  I'm a *lover* of multiple DEs installed (I select which I use at login) so my box has multiple installed; but I expect the same operation from apps for all (though my multi-DE does influence some aspects of my machine...)

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi seems it is too late for that but thanks.

Comment: @guiverc I do not think that is a good idea. A second answer will look like I m just trying to copy your answer. That would not help the OP and would not help me.

Comment: Fair enough...  and *Thank You!* for thinking of what is best for the community!  @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some desktops are WM *agnostic*, however some are not.  I'm using Lubuntu thus LXQt desktop which is a WM *agnostic* desktop; Lubuntu uses `openbox` as its WM; Debian use `xfwm4` (with LXQt)...

Yes almost all DEs *should* work with any WM, however you'll discover you may not get all functionality working as some are coded and expect certain WMs to be used.  I'm a *lover* of multiple DEs installed (*I select which I use at login*) so my box has multiple installed; but I expect the same operation from apps for all (*though my multi-DE does influence some aspects of my machine*...)

My current session is Lubuntu (LXQt using `openbox`) however if I logout and switched to another, eg. Xubuntu (Xfce) I'll have a different wallpaper, but as I've setup my panels to be on the same edges of the same monitors the difference *visually* is minimal, I'll just have a *mouse* replace the *bird* on my menu icons (ie. Xfce logo instead of LXQt).  I've set it up that way, ensuring my Qt5 & GTK themes work together well enough that I'm happy.  My `xfwm4` & `openbox` themese likewise match.  I could logout & use Ubuntu (GNOME) too; it's less visually like the other two (*doesn't have the same number of panels & other differences*) but its difference can be useful (*using it gives me a holiday from my normal setup*).

Key though is I'll use my apps the same way regardless of desktop though (*the major difference being the media keys work differently between DEs; I've made that the same before too, but have opted to leave that default now*).

I choose to use some different apps on the various environments (`qterminal` when using Lubuntu/LXQt, `xfce4-terminal` when using Xubuntu/Xfce, `gnome-terminal` when using Ubuntu/GNOME...) as they're the most efficient on those environments, and boxes with limited RAM I even use different text editors when I switch DEs, but as this box as 16GB of RAM I can use features that suit me; so some text files are always in `featherpad` (*regardless of my DE as it's setup perfectly for my usage*), others are in `mousepad` etc.  I decide what apps I use, unless the machine has limited resource (*I still use devices with 1GB of RAM where I'm ultra careful!*), or some tasks I'm performing really require those resources (*so I'm lean with what I can control*).

Regardless, on my multi-desktop installs I use the apps the same way regardless of my chosen session (*DE/WM choice*).

Comment: This is really a very long *opus* of @David's first comment "*All the same software should work on any DE or WM*".  I believe their are exceptions, though they are few & limited to specific circumstances, where the OP didn't provide any of note that I saw.